# How to schedule a failed email in PHP web application other than cron job method?

Tags: php

I'm working on web app where there's a requirement of sending an email at a scheduled time.
The correct scenario is: If mailing functionality fails for any reason, the retry attempt should take place after specific time periods till the mailing gets success.
So the question here is , if I have the mailing details recorded somewhere(mysql db table here) , how the retry mechanism implemented .
Can this be implemented without using cronjobs? If yes, how??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need some kind of cron system anyway, but it could simply be a third party service calling a specific page on your site. Why don't you want to use cronjobs in the first place ?

Then your process would only be to log any failed attempt in a queue and treat the queue (= send mails) each x hours. You could also consider having a max number of retry or something like this.

Comment: Or pay a monkey to press refresh on the `http://mywebsite.com/resend_failed_email.php` script. You could name him CROM as you dont want CRON

Comment: p.s. If you dont have cron on your server, get somewhere else to run it using `wget http://mywebsite.com/resend_failed_email.php` ie open webpage. but your script would have to be visible on the web

Comment: I didn't think about the monkey indeed :-) Better to hire 2 of them in order for the second to take over when the first one scratches his butt :-)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bartdute. :). So i've decided to use cronjob itself to run mail retry script of my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a scheduled time I would definitely use a cronjob. To make sure that e-mails are send just use a true/false loop which checks if its send or not.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and create one page which contains an infinite loop. this is completely untested and I have never implemented anything like this before - it is only a suggestion:

```
$hourToSend = 17; //this is the specified time to send (e.g. an hour, day, week..)

while(1)
{
    start:
    if(emailNotSent() == true && date('H') == $hourToSend) //boolean (function or variable) set after the email script has executed. could even be an array of email IDs.
    {
        resendEmail();
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(3600); //set an interval to check for failed emails, default = every hour
        goto start;
    }
}
```

this assumes you have access to a server with good uptime which would not be effected by one browser window open all the time (could be of benefit for monitoring, reporting, logging, &c.).

+1 for interesting question, comments and suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

For emails, you shouldn't be using cron in the first place. *Any* capable [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) should be able to queue messages that it can't send - it's a *requirement*.

Comment: That covers some reasons that "mailing functionality fails", but not all. Indeed, as it is unlikely the MTA is reporting bounces back to the PHP app, I assume that for this question, "failed email" exclusively means "web app is unable to communicate with MTA".

Comment: "web app is unable to communicate with MTA" will not be resolved by trying the same thing again (unless you've got really innapropriate administration procedures)

Comment: ....and if the email is important, then not having a process for handling bounces (automated or manual) is not very sensible. Why should it be unlikely?

Comment: It is entirely possible that a PHP web app will not connect to an SMTP server one minute but will the next. They are different processes, possibly on different machines. There is no "appropriate administration procedure" that'll ensure that they are both online and active at the same time. I agree with your basic assertion that an MTA should queue messages to resend; indeed that side can be taken for granted. I just don't think it is relevant. 

When the OP says he is sending an email he means through PHP, and when he says 'cron job' he will likely mean running a PHP script one way or another.

Comment: Or in short, the OP is talking about "mailing functionality", meaning "adding to the queue" (which can fail) and you're talking about "sending an email", meaning "trying to get the email to the recipient" (which can fail in a totally different way).